# If I need to whitelist Ably's servers from a firewall, which ports, IPs and/or domains should I add?

Tags: security, real-time, firewall, ably-realtime

I'm using [Ably](http://ably.io) to implement Pub/Sub over websockets. If I need to whitelist Ably's servers from a firewall, which ports, IPs and/or domains should I add?

*(disclaimer: I am a developer advocate for Ably, and posting and self-answering a [commonly asked support question](https://support.ably.io/support/solutions/articles/3000066636-if-i-need-to-whitelist-ably-s-servers-from-a-firewall-which-ports-ips-and-or-domains-should-i-add-) here on Stack Overflow so our users can find this more easily)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports

All of Ably's client libraries exclusively use the standard HTTPS port 443 for [WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/concepts/websockets) and HTTP traffic over TLS.

When configured to not use TLS, port 80 is used. Please note we rarely recommend anyone uses an unencrypted connection and this is disabled by default in all client libraries.

If using our Ably Protocol Adapters and/or our Ably Reactor service, the following ports are used:

```
Reactor queue over AMQP - TLS only using port 5671
Reactor queue over STOMP - TLS only using port 61614
MQTT adapter - port 8883 over TLS and port 1883 for unencrypted socket
PubNub adapter - HTTPS only using port 443
Pusher adapter - HTTPS only using port 443
```

IPs and domain names

Unfortunately it is impossible for Ably to publish a set of IP addresses for the cloud based service as our service is elastic and IP addresses are reassigned dynamically as a normal part of our service. If IP based restrictions are needed, please get in touch with us to discuss an Enterprise account with a dedicated cluster and fixed set of IPs.

Ably's client libraries by default connect to Ably using the following domains:

```
REST requests - rest.ably.io
Realtime (WebSocket) connections - realtime.ably.io
Fallback hosts - a.ably-realtime.com, b.ably-realtime.com, c.ably-realtime.com, d.ably-realtime.com, e.ably-realtime.com. Please see the documentation on why we provide a fallback host feature.
```

Please note that customers using custom CNAMEs will have a different set of primary REST and Realtime domains, and may also have a different set of fallback host domains.  Please contact us to find out more about your domains.

If using our Ably Protocol Adapters and/or our Ably Reactor service, the following domains are used:

```
Reactor Queue US East 1 - us-east-1-a-queue.ably.io
Reactor Queue other regions - get in touch
MQTT adapter - mqtt.ably.io
PubNub adapter - pubnub-rest.ably.io
Pusher adapter - pusher-rest.ably.io and pusher-realtime.ably.io
```

See [ably.io](http://ably.io)